# MYSQL: Get row where one specific property is smaller than a few other

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know how to do this kind of query:

I have one table with a bunch of properties. In these properties, there are 'distanceSydney, distanceBrisbane, distanceCanberra' and so on..

I'd like to **count** the number of rows where for example, distanceSydney is the smallest. 
I think I need a MIN() function that would return the smallest of the args we give it. I couldn't find this function...

I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM  `shops` WHERE MIN( `distanceSydney`, `distanceCanberra` ) = `distanceSydney`
```

But of course, MySQL error.

Thanks in advance!
Bastien.

Comment: Adding the error message might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM shops
WHERE distanceSydney < distanceCanberra
AND distanceSydney < distanceBrisbane
AND distanceSydney < distanceMelbourne
-- etc for other distance columns
```

Comment: Arf, so simple it didn't cross my mind... Thanks a lot Bohemian!

Answer (score 1):

Won't this do?

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM shops WHERE distanceSydney <= distanceCanberra
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`MIN` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/min.php) exists, you just have to use it a little differently. Get the minimal value first, and then `COUNT` the rows `WHERE` it's that value